# How to catch System.InvalidOperationException: Connection was disconnected before invocation result was received

Tags: xamarin, signalr, signalr.client

I´m getting this error exactly how the exception message says.
If a mobile client loses connection before the `proxy.Invoke()` result arrive, the exception is raised. That´s ok, but I need to catch this to avoid an app crash.
I try/catch all the `proxy.Invoke()` and `proxy.Invoke<T>()` calls, with no effect though.

How can I catch that exception?

**Note**: I´m using SignalR client 2.2.0 in a Xamarin client (PCL)

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling your `proxy.Invoke()` without `await proxy.Invoke()` then the exception won't bubble up from the `Invoke` task to your executing code.
I've had to deal with this error before (with Xamarin in a PCL), and simply executing my `Invoke` like such worked for me:

```
try
{
    await hubProxy.Invoke("SomeMethod", args);
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    // Do what you need to with the exception
}
```

There is also a conversation about it [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2631) on the SignalR GitHub.

Comment: Hi!, I always use `await` but I was catching `Exception` instead of `InvalidOperationException`. I´ll let you know if that works